# Pandas DataFrame with columns for arrays of different dimension

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, pandas

I have a set of data associated with Npts points. Some of that data are scalar values, such as color, some of the data are multi-dimensional, such as 3d position. I am trying to bundle this data into a pandas data structure, and get a variety of error messages depending on how I try to do it.

Here's some mock data:

```
Npts=100
pos = np.random.uniform(0, 250, Npts*3).reshape(Npts, 3)
colors = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, Npts)
```

Using a dictionary as input, the color data alone bundles up into a Data Frame just fine:

```
df_colors = pandas.DataFrame({'colors':colors})
```

But the position information does not:

```
df_pos = pandas.DataFrame({'pos':pos})
```

This returns the following unhelpful error message:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index
```

And what I really want to do is bundle *both* position and color information together:

```
df_agg = pandas.DataFrame({'pos':pos, 'colors':colors})
```

But this does not work, and returns the following equally cryptic error:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Surely it is possible to bundle multi-dimensional data with pandas, as well as data with mixed dimension. Does anyone know the API for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pos` has dimensions of (100,3). To turn it into a column, you need an array of dimensions (100,).

One option is to create an individual column for each of the dimensions:

```
df_agg = pandas.DataFrame({'posX':pos[:,0], 'posY':pos[:,1], 'posZ':pos[:,2], 'colors':colors})
```

Another options is to cast each coordinate into a 3-tuple:

```
posTuple = tuple(map(tuple,pos))
df_aggV2 = pandas.DataFrame({'pos':posTuple, 'colors':colors})
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. This works, but I don't understand why. I mean, you are right, it works. But I don't think it can be due to shape change. np.shape(pos) = (100, 3), and np.shape(posTuple) = (100, 3).
I'd like to keep the data type as a numpy array, if possible. 
Why does simply making the data tuple (or also a list: list(map(list,pos)) works just as well) solve the pandas error?

Comment: Ok, Andrew, I just confirmed. The reason your solution works is due to the type change. If I simply use list(pos) instead of pos, this solves the problem. Though I still don't understand why.

Comment: When you use a dict as your data input for DataFrame, only certain types of values are acceptable. My solutions cast the data into acceptable types. "DataFrame accepts many different kinds of input: ... Dict of 1D ndarrays, lists, dicts, or Series".

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe